# What is the criteria for "Event Failed" for Temporize on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

According to New Relic, the endpoint for Temporize hitting my app has a minimum response time of 20.9ms and a max of 355ms over the last 3 days. It doesn't have any record of any timeouts anywhere.

However I still get an email almost every day from Temporize saying "Event Failed" and "This event will be retried in one hour." I login to Temporize, and I see my daily job has a dot on the graph for every day, and no information about failures.

If the event didn't time out, why would I be getting an email about failures? How can I prevent these emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Heroku documentation:

> A callback can fail for many different reasons. Your application may be down or in the process of restarting, there may be a problem in the network connection, the application process may be hung, etc… Temporize treats any error during a connection attempt, any response that takes longer than 30 seconds, or any HTTP response code other than 2xx as a failure. When this happens, Temporize will attempt to retry the callback five times, at one hour intervals. Once the application has responded successfully (with a 2xx response code) the retries will be canceled. In addition, if the time of a retry is later than the next scheduled occurance of a recurring event, the retry will be canceled in order to prevent unexpected duplicate callbacks.

Does your URL have 3xx redirect HTTP code? Also, make sure there is no 304 status code (not modified) so set your cache headers for the event url correctly.